# Grunt html validation plugin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have installed grunt html validation plugin
[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-validation)

Registered task.

But have error when i call this task from command link

error like this

```
Network error re-validating.. 1
```

My register task look likes:

```
    validation: {
        files: {
            src: ['dist/index.html']
        }
    }
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-validation');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['validation']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/praveenvijayan/grunt-html-validation/issues/78). In short: the plugin is unusable now.

You can use [grunt-w3c-html-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-w3c-html-validation) plugin instead of it.